# Tomoko is making dishes and what's the probability of getting a chicken and dessert?

Tags: probability

Tomoka places her favorite recipes in a recipe book. She has 5 chicken dishes, 4 fish dishes, 3 soups, and 8 desserts. If Tomoka picks 2 distinct recipes at random from the book, what is the probability that she selects a chicken dish and a dessert (in any order)?

I got 4/19.

There are 20 choose 2 combinations = 190
There are 40 chicken and desert combinations (5 x 8)
40/190 = 4/19

Is this correct?  Please let me know!

Comment: The answer is correct, but it might be worth noting that the 40 in your answer comes from multiplying $${8\choose1}\times{5\choose1}$$ where you are choosing one of each of these two sets. That will help you in the case that you have to do a more complicated problem.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  For example, if the problem were instead 1 chicken dish, and 2 desserts.  Then we'd need to do 8 choose 2 times 5 choose 1, right?

Thank you for pointing that out! :)

Comment: Also credits to you for converting your earlier three-in-one question with little context into one question here with a lot of context!

Comment: You can type $\binom{20}{2}$ by typing `$\binom{20}{2}$`.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: FWIW, I'd be willing to answer your question about the t-shirts *if* you post it as a separate question and you include you method of solving as you did in the comments.  You did have the right answer and there is an equation/inequality to solve.

Comment: @fleablood thank you, I gave it a bit more thought and realized I could set up (100 - 5x)(10 + x).  Foiling it will give me a quadratic equation and I found the vertex of the parabola!